# subir un fichero en local laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero subir un fichero desde un formulario en Laravel.

```
Input::file('imagen')->move('/public/imagenes/asdf',$producto->id.Input::file('imagen')->getClientOriginalName());
```

He probado esto pero no funciona, me da este error:

> Call to a member function move() on null

Comment: Buenas, ¿te ha servido alguna de las respuestas? Si es así por favor, acepta la respuesta, si no sabes como, aquí tienes la forma correcta de hacerlo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas usando `Input` cuando a quien tienes que hacer referencia es a `$request` que es quien tiene el temporal del archivo.

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de la propia Wiki de Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads

En el ejemplo están usando `Storage`, pero te vale el `move` una vez tienes el nombre de la variable dentro de `$request`.

Para no copiar y pegar, te dejo las diferencias entre `Input` y `$request`

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/input-vs-request?page=1

Answer (score 1):

alguna vez lo hice asi espero te sirva:

```
        $file = Input::file('file');

        $destinationPath = public_path(). '/img/';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $producto = new Producto();

        $producto->img_path = 'img/'.$filename;
        $producto->save();
```